# Temperature of water vapour above water

Tags: energy, temperature, water, phase-transition

An open beaker containing water is being heated.
My understanding is that the molecules with the highest energy will escape as water vapour.
That would lead me to expect the temperature of the water vapour near the surface would be higher than that of the water, which I dont feel can be correct.
I'd expect the temperature above and below the surface at the interface to be the same.

Can anyone please explain in simple terms what is happening here?

Comment: It's a question of how far from a dynamic equilibrium your system is.

Answer (score 1):

A piece of wet cloth from which water evaporates will have a lower temperature than the surrounding air.

As long as the relative humidity is below 100 %, there is no equilibrium. Evaporation of sweat is how humans can maintain a physiological body temperature even when the air temperature is higher.

Answer (score 0):

If the change of phase is happening slowly, with the whole system in equilibrium at each stage, then the temperature is uniform throughout the system. As the heat is supplied, liquid changes to vapour. If heat is removed, vapour changes to liquid. The system is moving along an isotherm; its temperature is both uniform throughout liquid and vapour, and also constant as the phase change takes place. If there were any internal temperature gradients then heat would flow internally until they were ironed out.

From a molecular point of view, a molecule moving from liquid to vapour has to climb a potential gradient. It gains potential energy and loses kinetic energy. So any molecules making the journey end up with less kinetic energy than they had in the liquid. In equilibrium more of the faster molecules makes this journey. As a result, unless heat is supplied, the temperature of the liquid must fall (as indeed it does when no heat is supplied). But the vapour will not be hotter than the liquid because of the slowing down as the molecules escape from the attractive forces provided by the liquid. The average kinetic energy of molecules in the vapour ends up equal to the average kinetic energy of those remaining in the liquid.

If the temperature overall has not changed (e.g. because the pressure is being kept constant while heat is provided) then the system overall must have expanded and much of the provided energy from the heat source is used up as the system does work against its surroundings in order to expand.

Finally, there is the widely observed fact that things often cool down when liquid evaporates from them, so temperature changes can happen. To understand this it is best to look both at the bulk properties and the molecular motions. Consider first the coexistence curve, which is the curve showing the pressure as a function of temperature when the system is in phase equilibrium (i.e. evaporating or condensing). The vapour pressure goes up with temperature. So if the pressure is reduced by some external effect, then the temperature at which the system changes phase will also reduce. In the case of evaporation on a sunny day, or a windy day, either convection or the wind carries away the water vapour and replaces it with dry air. So this lowers the vapour pressure and the liquid will consequently evaporate at a lower temperature. The evaporation itself leaves a lower kinetic energy per molecule on average in the liquid, and this energy is not replaced by a heat source, so overall there is cooling. The second effect produces cooling, the first effect ensures the process does not stop as soon as it got started.

Cooling during evaporation can also happen when things are not in equilibrium. But note, this is not what the question mainly asked about. Even during such cooling, there is no temperature gradient between liquid and vapour. Both get colder together if the whole process is happening slowly enough. If it is not slow then all bets are off: the air temperature will then depend on what other processes are affecting it, and how fast the internal flows of energy can equalize the temperatures.

Comment: When there is evaporation, a temperature gradient will develop.

Comment: @Pieter  Not if the process is quasistatic (an example of de Chatelier's principle and related physics of entropy)

Comment: When the vapor phase is not saturated (say RH 70 % or 90 % or 95 %) there is no way that there could be an arbitrarily slow process. A temperature gradient would arise (if the volume of water is not very large etc).

Comment: @Pieter Yes I see what you mean. But I think it is important also to present the physical concept of equilibrium and all that it entails. In particular, evaporation can in principle be quasistatic even if in practice in many situations it is not.